# How can I trigger my animation on parent and all children in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a block quote in my `HTML` which contains words inside different span classes like so:

```
<div class="quote" id="quote">
  <blockquote> 
      <p>       
      <span class="left-quote">“</span>
      <span>This</span>
      <span>is</span>
      <span>my</span>
      <span>quote</span>
      <span class="right-quote">”</span>
      </p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

I have then applied animation to the quote in my CSS so that the text slowly fades in. Here is my CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.quote p {
  font-family: "Montserrat Medium";
  max-width: 40ch;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.94);
  animation: scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1);
}

@keyframes scale {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(4px);
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(5) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(6) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do now is to have this animation occur when the user scrolls to the section of the page where the `div` is active.

I am using the following to achieve this:

```
const element = document.getElementById('quote');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
element.classList.toggle('quote', entries[0].isIntersecting );
});
observer.observe(element)
```

However this will only trigger the animation on the quote which I believe is this part:

```
.quote p {
  font-family: "Montserrat Medium";
  max-width: 40ch;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.94);
  animation: scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1);
}
```

How can I get the animation to work on the span and each of the words?

I tried using these but both were unsuccessful:

```
const element = document.getElementById('quote');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
element.classList.toggle('quote span', entries[0].isIntersecting );
});
observer.observe(element)
```

And this:

```
const element = document.getElementById('quote');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
element.classList.toggle('quote', 'span', entries[0].isIntersecting );
});
observer.observe(element)
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.quote p {
  font-family: "Montserrat Medium";
  max-width: 40ch;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0.94);
  animation: scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1);
}
@keyframes scale {
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: blur(4px);
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.2s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.4s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(5) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.5s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

span:nth-child(6) {
  animation: fade-in 0.8s 0.6s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- Head -->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cedarville+Cursive&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="blur.css">
</head>

<!-- Body -->
<body>

    <div class="quote" id="quote">
        <blockquote>
          <p>
            <span class="left-quote">“</span>
            <span>This</span>
            <span>is</span>
            <span>my</span>
            <span>quote</span>
            <span class="right-quote">”</span>      
          </p>
        </blockquote>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without HTML your CSS, and JavaScript both lack context; thank you for providing code (genuinely!) but we need *enough* code to meaningfully answer questions in a way that's useful for you, and also for those with similar problems that look at the question in the future.

Comment: I understand. I have edited and re-phrased so I am hoping this is clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know how your HTML looks. I have to make an educated guess for how this should look as output.

```js
const quoteElements = document.querySelectorAll('.quote');
quoteElements.forEach((element) => {
  const childBlockquotes = element.querySelectorAll('blockquote');
  childBlockquotes.forEach((blockquote, index) => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
        blockquote.classList.add('fade-in-quote');
      } else {
        blockquote.classList.remove('fade-in-quote');
      }
    }, {
      root: element,
      threshold: 0.1  // Adjust as needed
    });
    observer.observe(blockquote);
  });
});
```

```css
.quote {
    height:100vh;
    overflow:auto;
  }
  
  .quote p {
    transform: scale(0.94);
    animation: scale 3s forwards cubic-bezier(0.5, 1, 0.89, 1);
  }
  
  @keyframes scale {
    100% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
  
  .quote span, .quote blockquote {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(4px);
    min-height:30vh;
    width:100%;
  }
  .fade-in-quote {
    animation: fade-in-quote 0.8s 0.1s forwards cubic-bezier(0.11, 0, 0.5, 0);
  }
  
  @keyframes fade-in-quote {
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      filter: blur(0);
    }
  }
  
  blockquote {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 2vmax;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;  
    border-top-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  .left-quote, .right-quote { 
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif;
  }
```

```html
<div class="quote">
    <blockquote>Quote 1</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 2</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 3</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 4</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 5</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 6</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 7</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 8</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 9</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 10</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 11</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 12</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 13</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 14</blockquote>
    <blockquote>Quote 15</blockquote>
</div>
```

I have made it so that if you have multiple quote blocks, it will look for `.quote` and iterate over these and apply the same to each `.quote` on the page.

You have to modify for it to fit your `HTML`, but I hope this `JS` will help you on the way. Have a great day!